# React Native / Javascript async await

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to know why the code works like this:

```
async function Signin({ email, pass, confirmpass }) {
  const body = {
    'email': email,
    'pass': pass,
    'confirmpass': confirmpass,
  };
  const params = {
    endpoint: 'register_user',
    method: 'post',
    headers: null,
    body: body
  }
  const result = await api.connect(params);
  console.log(result);
}
```

but it doesn't work like this:

```
async function Signin({ email, pass, confirmpass }) {
  let result = await registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass, });
  console.log(result);

  // TODO: api call 2
  // TODO: api call 3
  
}

async function registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass }) {
  const body = {
    'email': email,
    'pass': pass,
    'confirmpass': confirmpass,
  };
  const params = {
    endpoint: 'register_user',
    method: 'post',
    headers: null,
    body: body
  }
  return api.connect(params);
}
```

It logs the following error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

I have to make three calls to the api, so to make it more readable and easier to maintain I want to make the api calls in different functions.

I don't have much experience with JS Async/Await, I just started using it because I need to do something in React Native, I was from PHP before.

Update: I did like @safder said onj the comment and used try catch but now it doesn't wait the result

```
async function Signin({ email, pass, confirmpass }) {
  try {
    let result = await registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass, });
    console.log(result);
  } catch {

  }

  // TODO: api call 2
  // TODO: api call 3

}

async function registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass }) {
  let result = null;
  const body = {
    'email': email,
    'pass': pass,
    'confirmpass': confirmpass,
  };
  const params = {
    endpoint: 'register_user',
    method: 'post',
    headers: null,
    body: body
  }
  try {
   result = api.connect(params);
  } catch {

  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Safder Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Comment: You need to wrap it in a try/catch block for async/await

Comment: An unhandled promise rejection means you're calling an asynchronous function without wrapping it in a `try ... catch` block or using `.catch()` to catch any potential errors.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't wait for the result, thats why i remove it

Comment: `try/catch` does not preclude waiting for the result. Can you show your attempt at that?

Comment: @jnpdx just update the question with the code

Comment: You have a redundant `try/catch`. You could just `return api.connect(params)` and keep the `try/catch` around the call site (`let result = await registerUser`)

Comment: I did that but still got null, add to rebuild the project and it works, tank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tank you @Safder, @ftrsk and @jnpdx

I need to use try catch on the first function and the second didn't need to be async.

```
async function Signin({ email, pass, confirmpass, }) {
  try {
    var result = await registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass, });
    console.log(result);
  } catch {

  }
  
}

function registerUser({ email, pass, confirmpass, }) {
  const body = {
    'email': email,
    'pass': pass,
    'confirmpass': confirmpass,
  };
  const params = {
    endpoint: 'register_user',
    method: 'post',
    headers: null,
    body: body
  }

  return api.connect(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not waiting for
`api.connect(params)`
to execute. Always make sure to put await before an asynchronous function. You can fix the problem in the second code block by putting

```html
const result = await api.connect(params)
return result
```

or even

```html
return await api.connect(params)
```

Comment: If I do that VS Code returns this message: Redundant use of `await` on a return value.sonarlint(javascript:S4326)